# javaScript if window.location.href contains url1 do not run else run it

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I want to do not execute script if page url contains specific strings like url1
this is my code but it doesn't work!

```
var chick = window.location.href.indexOf('url1') == -1;
if (! chick) {
   // do something but don't do it if url contains url1
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `indexOf()` comparison with `-1` returns `true` if `window.location.href` does **not** contain the url you are looking for. So you need to change it to

```
var chick = window.location.href.indexOf('url1') == -1;
if (chick) {
   // do something but don't do it if url contains url1
}
```

Or to give it a certain sense, reverse the condition and return `true` if it contains:

```
var chick = window.location.href.indexOf('url1') > -1;
if (!chick) {
   // do something but don't do it if url contains url1
}
```